# Grails SpringSecurity: browser doesn't offer to save login/password for the page

Tags: security, authentication, grails, autocomplete

There is an app with a default `grails.plugins.springsecurity` authentication. When I enter login/password in Opera [12.14] it offers me to store the login/password for the page, while Chrome, FF and IE don't.

Does this have to be configured on the page somehow or is this browser-specific?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's intentional, as a security precaution - it's due to the nonstandard `autocomplete='off'` attribute in the `form` tag. Apparently Opera ignores it, while the other browsers do the right thing. If you want to allow this, remove the attribute from your `auth.gsp` file.